# Qwiic Real Time Clock Module not working when changing I2C pinout

Tags: arduino, esp8266, real-time-clock

I am trying to get the Qwiic Real Time Clock Module by Sparkfun working. I am using an esp8266. The clock works fine with the standard I2C pinouts, but when I change it with `Wire.begin(2, 3);`, it suddenly doesn't work anymore.

I've tried changing the pinouts to other examples (`Wire.begin(0, 1);` etc.) but nothing semes to work. I checked the wiring a ton of times and I think it is correct.

As code, I am just using a modified example written by Sparkfun.

This is my code:

```
void setup() {
  Wire.begin(2 , 3);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Read Time from RTC Example");

  while(1) {
    if (rtc.begin() == false) {
      Serial.println("Something went wrong, check wiring");
    } else
      break;
    delay(1000);
  }

  if (rtc.setToCompilerTime() == false) {
    Serial.println("Something went wrong setting the time");
  }

  Serial.println("RTC online!");
}

void loop() { }
```

When i run the Program, it just stays in the while loop and never progresses further.

Comment: pins 0 and 3 are Serial

Comment: I know, but I rly need to use them, as no other pins are free to use.

Comment: then don't do Serial.begin()

Comment: i also need to use Serial connection for a E-Paper Display

Comment: I have 3 empty pins left: 1, 2 and 3

Comment: correction: 1 and 3 are Serial.

Comment: you don't have 1 and 3 if you use Serial

Comment: what esp8266 board is it?

Comment: Universal e-Paper raw Panel Driver Board, ESP8266 WiFi Wireless

Comment: what occupies io 4 and 5?

Comment: Thank you for your help, D4 isn't free but D5 is and it works with `Wire.begin(14, 2);`

Comment: 14 is used for SPI for the e-paper

Comment: io 4 and 5 are labeled D1 D2. this are default Wire pins for esp9266. how do you use them?

Comment: I have a ink-Display connected. It uses the pins: 4, 5, 15, 16

Comment: The red pinnouts are the ones my programm uses: https://imgur.com/a/XQQLV3W, so if spi uses 12, 13, 14 and 15 and serial uses 1 and 3, i would only have pin 2 left. Is this correct?

Comment: the 4, 5, and 16 are additional connections of the SPI display? 15 is CS. how are 4, 5 and 16 used?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. 4, 5 and 16 are used by the display.

Comment: Ok i figered out a way to save the 0 pin. Now it works